# How to remove repetition between similar python classes

Tags: python, class

I currently have two classes: Block and Pic

Unfortunately they are almost identical. I'm looking for the best way to remove the repeated parts across the two classes.

```
class Block(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, colour, width, height):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(colour)

    def invert(self):
        self.image = inverted(self.image)

    def set_speed(self, speed):
        self.speed = speed

class Pic(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.image = pygame.image.load('icon.png').convert()

    def invert(self):
        self.image = inverted(self.image)

    def set_speed(self, speed):
        self.speed = speed
```

Comment: How about creating a common base class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about creating a common base class?

```
class BaseClass(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    'baseclass for your derived classes, feel free to choose a better name'
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

    def invert(self):
        self.image = inverted(self.image)

    def set_speed(self, speed):
        self.speed = speed

class Block(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self, colour, width, height):
        super(Block, self).__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(colour)

class Pic(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Pic, self).__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load('icon.png').convert()
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`class inheritance`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance), i.e. create a class with the common parts and class methods and derive your classes `Block` and `Pic` from this new class.

Some examples are given here: http://www.jesshamrick.com/2011/05/18/an-introduction-to-classes-and-inheritance-in-python/